# Register Custom Post Type from Plugin

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

I'm trying to register a CPT from a plugin upon activation but seem to have hit a wall...  Anyone see anything im missing?  I don't get any errors but the CPT doesn't show up in the dashboard links....

```
    function ctg_cpt_init() {
    register_post_type( 'ctg_questions',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Questions' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Question' )
                ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'questions' )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'ctg_cpt_init' );

function ctg_rewrite_flush() {
    ctg_cpt_init();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'ctg_rewrite_flush' );
```

Thanks,

Comment: I tried your code and the CPT showed up in the Administration Panels primary navigation menu. Do you mean that you're trying to get it to show up in the 'Right Now' meta box on the dashboard?

Comment: Now she's working for me too!  I changed the function namespaces before posting here - must've had a keying error.  Thanks for everyones help and appologies for the time waster...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull the CPT registration functionality out of the *Plugin activation* hook, so that it can fire at `init`, where you want it to.

The Plugin activation hook is a one-time only hook; you need your CPT to fire *every time* at the `init` hook, not just once.

Comment: He's calling register_post_type() inside a hook to 'init'. He's only flushing the rewrite rules during the register_activation_hook().