# How to create two custom post types when plugin is activated?

Tags: plugin-development

I am developing a plugin for question & answer.For that i need to create custom post types question & answer.How to link that custom post types so that if i display a post from Question the related answers should be displayed.How to create two custom posts simultaneously when the plugin is activated?

Comment: Please change the title, is not in the context with your question.

Comment: Look in the AgentPress Listings plugin.php file and class-listings.php file.

Comment: ok i will check that.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22749/register-custom-post-type-from-plugin/ This link is good but how to create two post types simultaneously is not mentioned here.You got any idea

Comment: function my_create_post_types() {
 register_post_type( 'my_post_type', $args);
 register_post_type( 'my_other_post_type', $args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_create_post_types' ); The first link and this function has to be combined in some way.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress have on default no relationship possibilities for the same objects, like custom post type. But you can create a custom table or use the meta data on each post to create a relationship.

#### Ready to use

Also it give usable ready solutions:

- [Post2Post plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/)
- [ACF Relationship Field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/)

#### For a custom solution about meta fields:

You find in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/128627/170) helpful hints and the source for a relationshep between the meta data.

Comment: You have got some custom codes so that i can understand what it is

Comment: I have enhanced the answer for more understanding. But I haven't add source, was redundant to a usable answer.

Comment: That link was really helpful.Thankyou

Comment: The idea is good for adding a field in one post type from other related post type.That is not what iam asking.Suppose we submit an answer for a question,how to relate that question & answer for displaying them correctly.Both questions & answers are seperate cpt.How to display corresponding answers when a question link is clicked.Please check this link http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-metabox-custom-post-type

Comment: Do you will display the answers to the questions in front end, 2 different CPTs? Or you will display this in a meta box inside the back end on the cpt question? But is not really different. The content inside the meta box or front end have the same loop to get the other CPT with the relationship from CPT "QuestioN" to CPT "Answer".

Comment: I think the idea is to get the question id and store it as separate field in answer cpt & display them as & when required.

Comment: Yes, store in the meta data of each CPT, the ID of Question on the meta data of Answer and also back, the ID of a answer in the meta data of the question. This is, what I mean on the answer and the last comment from my side.

Comment: Every answer is vague.I am fed up.I will search google.I am simply wasting time here.

Comment: The answer have solutions, but you must select your choice. If you like a ready usable solution, then explain your question for a explicit goal.